# How to add a field on the user creation page?

Tags: wp-admin, user-registration

How to add a field on the user creation page "/wp-admin/user-new.php"? I need to finish after exactly after the email field, I can’t understand how to do this (I understand that you can use the user_new_form action to add a field, but how to add it to a specific place on the page?

Comment: screen [link]https://pasteboard.co/Jc7qK3037dDs.png

Comment: There’s no hook to choose where to place new fields. They can only be added to the bottom. If you need it in a specific place then your only option is to move it with JavaScript after the page has loaded.

Comment: thanks! made with JavaScript)